# socket read not returning more data

Tags: c++, sockets, file-descriptor, epoll

I am learning epoll, I did a udp server application and client application just for demonstration. everything seems ok, however when the client tries to send a large packet, the server's read call can only gets the receive buffer full once but not the second time, 
to be precise, client sent 2090 bytes, server has a receive buffer of 1600 (I deliberately set it a little bigger than common MTU), and I only received once 1599 bytes, with the once extra bytes I kept as '\0'. but when the loop comes back, the next read does not get anything, hence the server only gets 1599 bytes, instead of the full 2090 bytes.

both server and client were running on the same host, going thru the only ethernet interface.

I also checked wireshark, captured the interface I am using, and there is indeed a udp packet of payload size 2090, not fragmented.

server side

```cpp
#include <spdlog/sinks/basic_file_sink.h>
#include <spdlog/sinks/stdout_sinks.h>
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <spdlog/async.h>

#include <base/argument_parser.hpp>
#include <string>

#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

using pull_cb_t = std::function<void(const char*, size_t)>;

struct input_channel {
public:
    pull_cb_t cb;
    int fd;
    std::string name;
    input_channel(pull_cb_t cb_, int _fd, std::string _name)
        : cb(cb_), fd(_fd), name(_name) {}

    void pull() {
        spdlog::info("{}", __func__);
        char buf[1600];
        //int pull_count = 0;
        while (true) {
            auto count = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
            if (count == -1) {
                if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                    spdlog::info("nothing to read, return");
                    return;
                }
                spdlog::info("error reading data from fd {}", errno);
                perror("read");
                return;
            }
            if (count == 0) {
                spdlog::info("read returns zero");
                return;
            }
            cb(buf, count);
            pull_count++;
        }
    }
};

static int make_socket_non_block(int sfd) {
    int flags;
    flags = fcntl(sfd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags == -1)
        EXIT_ERR("error geting flag %d", flags);

    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    if (fcntl(sfd, F_SETFL, flags) == -1) {
        EXIT_ERR("error setting non blocking %d", flags);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    std::string log_file;
    uint16_t listening_port = 5678;
    uint16_t max_event = 1024;

    dark::argument_parser ag;
    ASSERT_SUCCESS(ag.add_option([&](std::string input) { log_file = input; },
                                 'l', "log", "log file", false));

    ASSERT_SUCCESS(ag.parse(argc, argv));


    if (!log_file.empty()) {
        spdlog::init_thread_pool(8096, 1);
        auto sync = spdlog::basic_logger_mt<spdlog::async_factory>(
            "file", log_file, true);
        spdlog::set_default_logger(sync);
    }

    spdlog::info("creating a udp socket");

    int domain = AF_INET;
    int type = SOCK_DGRAM;
    int protocol = 0;
    auto udp_fd = socket(domain, type, protocol);
    if (udp_fd == -1)
        EXIT_ERR("failed to create udp fd %d", errno);

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.222");
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(listening_port);

    if (bind(udp_fd, (const struct sockaddr*)&server_addr,
             sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
        EXIT_ERR("failed to bind addr %d", errno);

    spdlog::info("created udp fd and bind with port={}", listening_port);
    make_socket_non_block(udp_fd);
    spdlog::info("fd is set to be non blocking");
    auto channel =
        std::make_unique<input_channel>([&](const char* data, size_t len) {
                                            std::string s(data, len);
                                            spdlog::info("received: len={}bytes [{}]",
                                                         len, s.c_str());
                                        },
                                        udp_fd, "udp_channel");


    spdlog::info("creating epoll obj");
    auto epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);
    if (epoll_fd == -1)
        EXIT_ERR("failed to create epoll %d", errno);

    struct epoll_event event;
    event.data.ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(channel.get());
    event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;

    if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, udp_fd, &event) == -1)
        EXIT_ERR("failed to add fd=%d to epoll_fd %d", udp_fd, errno);

    struct epoll_event* events =
        reinterpret_cast<epoll_event*>(calloc(max_event, sizeof(event)));

    while (true) {
        int n, i;
        n = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, max_event, 0);
        if (n == -1)
            EXIT_ERR("epoll error");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (events[i].events & EPOLLERR || events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) {
                spdlog::info("events error or hangup");
            } else if (events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
                spdlog::info("ready to read");
                auto c = reinterpret_cast<input_channel*>(events[i].data.ptr);
                c->pull();
            } else {
                spdlog::info("pulled something else");
            }
        }

        // spdlog::info("pulled nothing");
    }

    free(events);
    close(udp_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

client side

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string>

#include <base/argument_parser.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {

    uint16_t port;
    bool jumbo_mode = false;

    dark::argument_parser ag;
    ASSERT_SUCCESS(
        ag.add_option([&](std::string input) { port = std::stoi(input); }, 'p',
                      "port", "port to use", true));
    ASSERT_SUCCESS(
        ag.add_flag(&jumbo_mode, 'j', "jumbo", "send jumbo packets", false));

    ASSERT_SUCCESS(ag.parse(argc, argv));

    int sockfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    std::string s = "Hello from client";
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.2.222");

    int n;
    unsigned int len;

    size_t total_bytes = 0;
    std::string new_s;
    int i = 0;
    if (!jumbo_mode) {
        while (true) {
            new_s = s + "-" + std::to_string(i);
            total_bytes += new_s.size();
            auto ret =
                sendto(sockfd, new_s.c_str(), new_s.size(), MSG_CONFIRM,
                       (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
            printf("Hello message sent [%s] total_bytes=%lu.\n", new_s.c_str(),
                   total_bytes);
            if (ret < 0)
                printf("error in sendto");
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            new_s += s + "-" + std::to_string(j);
            new_s += " ";
        }
        total_bytes = new_s.size();
        auto ret = sendto(sockfd, new_s.c_str(), new_s.size(), MSG_CONFIRM,
                          (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
        printf("send msg ret=%ld total len=%lu [%s]\n", ret, total_bytes,
               new_s.c_str());
        if (ret < 0)
            printf("error in sendto");
    }

    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, MSG_WAITALL,
                 (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, &len);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("Server : %s\n", buffer);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to see the read returns another 490 bytes when called the next time.

Comment: What happened instead? End of stream? EAGAIN? Another error? NB You need to call `perror()` immediately, not after doing more system calls that could disturb `errno`.

Comment: Somehow mixing TCP and UDP. So setting up the connection with DGRAM, not listening and not accepting, OK. But then using read and not recvfrom. I am wondering that it reads at all. And, although the socket has been set to non blocking mode, I would guess that read blocks. Is only a guess. Too much mixing up modes. Does read really return with EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in the 2nd loop run? Sorry, Your code is hard to read . . .

Comment: the second read get EAGAIN, then it returns

Comment: @user207421 it was EAGAIN, I get the log "nothing to read"

Comment: @ArminMontigny it was non blocking, when the client does not send anything the read get EAGAIN all the time, just spinning there because of the epoll_wait using 0 timeout